# Whats causing the yellowing on my transplanted sweet potato slips

Tags: plant-health, transplanting

I transplanted my slips 2 days ago and they started yellowing like this it even happens overnight so i don't think it's a sun problem[image]

Comment: Are you overwatering? It's hard to say. I'd guess either that, poor soil, fungal disease, or nitrogen-deficiency.